# Magento 2 Class of custom module Collection does not exist

Tags: magento2, collection

I created a basic index controller that outputs the collection but for some reason I am getting the following error:

```
    {
    "0": "Class Debug\\Tool\\Model\\ResourceModel\\LoadModel\\Collection does not exist",
    "1": "#0 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Debug\\\\Tool\\\\Mode...')
#1 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\\Framework\\Code\\Reader\\ClassReader->getConstructor('Debug\\\\Tool\\\\Mode...')
#2 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(100): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Definition\\Runtime->getParameters('Debug\\\\Tool\\\\Mode...')
#3 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\Factory\\Compiled->create('Debug\\\\Tool\\\\Mode...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(508): Magento\\Framework\\ObjectManager\\ObjectManager->create('Debug\\\\Tool\\\\Mode...')
#5 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(521): Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel->getResourceCollection()
#6 /var/www/html/pixeltown/app/code/Debug/Tool/Controller/Tool/Index.php(37): Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel->getCollection()
#7 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Debug\\Tool\\Controller\\Tool\\Index->execute()
#8 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#9 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Debug\\Tool\\Controller\\Tool\\Index\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#10 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Debug\\Tool\\Controller\\Tool\\Index\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/pixeltown/generated/code/Debug/Tool/Controller/Tool/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Debug\\Tool\\Controller\\Tool\\Index\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#12 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Debug\\Tool\\Controller\\Tool\\Index\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#13 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#15 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/pixeltown/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#21 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/pixeltown/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()
#23 /var/www/html/pixeltown/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))
#24 {main}",
    "url": "/pixeltown/debug/tool/index",
    "script_name": "/pixeltown/index.php"
}
```

I have followed a specific tutorial regarding loading Collections and I have the filestructure the same more o less , I am thinking that it is something regarding the permission of the var/generated folder , but I have done the following aswell:

```
sudo php pixeltown/bin/magento setup:upgrade;sudo php pixeltown/bin/magento c:c;sudo php pixeltown/bin/magento setup:di:compile;sudo chmod 777 pixeltown/ -R
```

I will show the following code:

Debug\Tool\Controller\Tool\Index.php

```
<?php


namespace Debug\Tool\Controller\Tool;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; /* For controller we always use this class */

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory; /*We need to use this class (with Factory Added at the end) to show rendered page*/

use Debug\Tool\Model\ToolModelFactory; /*Delete later*/

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $pageFactory;
    protected $toolModelFactory;
    public function __construct(ToolModelFactory $toolModelFactory,PageFactory $pageFactory,Context $context)
    {
        $this->toolModelFactory = $toolModelFactory;
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $tool = $this->toolModelFactory->create();
        $collection = $tool->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $item){
            var_dump($item->getData());
            echo "</br>";
        }
        die();
        //var_dump($tool->load(52)->getData());die();
        return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

\Debug\Tool\Model\ToolModel.php

```
<?php


namespace Debug\Tool\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

use Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\LoadModel;
class ToolModel extends AbstractModel
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(LoadModel::class);
        //parent::_construct(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }


}
```

\Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\LoadModel.php

```
<?php


namespace Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb; /*We always need to extend AbstractDB*/

class LoadModel extends AbstractDb
{

    /**
     * Resource initialization
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        // TODO: Implement _construct() method.
        $this->_init('core_config_data','config_id');
    }
}
```

\Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection.php

```
<?php


namespace Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\Post;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Debug\Tool\Model\ToolModel;
use Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\LoadModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(ToolModel::class,LoadModel::class);
        //parent::_construct(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

I access debug/tool/index in url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good evening,

it looks like your collection namespace is wrong.

You have `Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\Post` but it has to be `Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\LoadModel` at least if you want to use `collection = $tool->getCollection()`.

Reason is on model initialization the resource names are set.

```
File: /lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/AbstractModel.php
Line: 213
    protected function _init($resourceModel)
    {
        $this->_setResourceModel($resourceModel);
        $this->_idFieldName = $this->_getResource()->getIdFieldName();
    }
Line: 456
    protected function _setResourceModel($resourceName, $collectionName = null)
    {
        $this->_resourceName = $resourceName;
        if ($collectionName === null) {
            $collectionName = $resourceName . '\\' . 'Collection';
        }
        $this->_collectionName = $collectionName;
    }
```

As you can see the collection name is concatenated using the resource model class name and appending `\Collection`. Since your resource model resides under `Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\LoadModel` you would end up with a collection class name of `Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\LoadModel\Collection`. However your actual namespace is `Debug\Tool\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection` thus it can't find your collection.

**P.S:** A better way would be to inject the collection as a factory into your controller because `getCollection()` is deprecated. You should avoid using it.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I changed has you said but not I get 500 error, this is the log [2019-09-19 01:43:22] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
[2019-09-19 01:43:34] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/pixeltown/debug/tool/index","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Comment: Have you cleared the cache(php bin/magento cache:cl)? Did you change the directory name as well?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Yest I did , this is the directory structure https://imgur.com/5MbNKCy and this is the collection  https://imgur.com/eKXseJT

Comment: I rebuild your module excluding the part in view folder since I don't know what it contains. So far it works https://imgur.com/a/eiTGh2K. Also it is a 500 error so something server side. Maybe you try to check server logs as well.

Comment: I checked /var/log/apache2/error.log  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Debug\\Tool\\Model\\Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractModel' not found in /var/www/html/pixeltown/app/code/Debug/Tool/Model/ToolModel.php on line 7
 I modified it and now it seems to be working,thanks a lot,I still not sure why the namespace was a issue, maybe its because the getCollection method in the model? well in any case this helped me alot, thanks!